# How to specify uploadType for Insert function in Google Drive SDK java client

Tags: java, google-drive-api

In the Google Drive SDK for the insert function the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) says that the uploadType parameter is required and can take 3 values. But it does not specify how this value can be defined when using the java client. it is not clear whether the example uses a simple, multipart or resumable. How do you define the uploadType in the java api.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem a while back. For those encountering this issue in future, a good answer has just been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918045/2201154